# Exporting a variable to another bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a bash script ex.sh that calls another script path.sh

```
sh path.sh
```

I have a variable in path.sh that I would like to use in ex.sh

I tried

```
export var
```

and then called it in ex.sh using

```
echo 'export HOME=${var}' >> /etc/profile.d/user_env.sh
```

This is not working, Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't use single-quotes here if you want expansion to occur.

Comment: @jquerynoob you are supposed to accept the answer which is best suited for you as a courtesy to others who spend some time helping you. If you are not satisfied then feel free to add comments on the provided answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export` recognizes a variable or function to its sub-shells.
Instead, inside ex.sh, **source** the path.sh script like below ->

```
. ./path.sh
```

or like this ->

```
source ./path.sh
```

That way, all declared variables and functions of path.sh becomes available in current script (ex.sh in this case)

If path.sh is doing some more work other than declaring variables and functions then have a separate third script set_var.sh and source that in both path.sh and ex.sh

Comment: This would be necessary if you wanted `path.sh` -- the child process -- to expose variables to the caller. It is **not** necessary going in the other direction when all variables necessary are exported -- which is to say, when *environment* variables from the caller to be visible to its child processes.

Comment: Well he can customize it using by having third script whatever he wants to expose it to ex.sh

Comment: (By the way -- if the downvote on my answer was from you, a comment explaining why and how its contents are inaccurate would be appreciated).

Comment: *nod*. As nothing you say here is inaccurate, I'm staying neutral on yours as well. Accept my apologies for the accusation.

Comment: Now someone has downvoted my ans as well without any comments :-(

Comment: @Amon, re: your edit -- `source` is a bash extension, not present in POSIX sh. It might be worth presenting that caveat when describing it as an alternative, as the original answer by @dganesh2002 was POSIX-compliant.

Comment: Thx. feel free to edit. Anyhow, the problem is the attempt to use `export`. since `export` works down i.e. recognizes to sub-shells and the question tries to recognize variables up i.e. to a parent shell.

Comment: @dganesh2002 Thank you, I exported the variable, sourced it in a file and I was able to use the variables in another bash script.

Comment: @Arnon Zilca Nice call on the suggestion of creating a separate set_var.sh file.

Answer (score 2):

The parent process can't get variable from the child. You should to use some form of communication between processes to exchange data. You can use:

- file

  - the child write the info into an file, like: `newvar=someval`
  - when the child exits, the parent `source` the file and get the `newvar` variable

or

- named pipe

  - the parent create a fifo
  - runs the child in the background and start read from the pipe
  - the child write the information to the pipe
  - parent read it...

demo:

file: `parent.sh`

```
commfile="./.ex.$$"
echo "the newvar before child: =$newvar="
bash child.sh "$commfile"
source "$commfile"
echo "the newvar after source: =$newvar="
rm -f "$commfile"
```

file: `child.sh`

```
commfile="$1"
#do something
sleep 2
echo "newvar='some value'" >"$commfile"
```

running `parent.sh` prints:

```
the newvar before child: ==
the newvar after source: =some value=
```